# amchart Trend Lines change theme

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have sum issues with Trend Lines chart.
when change chart.theme , it does not affect (chart.theme="patterns";) 
please help me.
this is my sample.

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/qncgx096/1/]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use API-fashioned way to create you chart you need to initiate the chart instance with the theme like following:

```
chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart(AmCharts.themes.patterns);
```

Ensure you don't overwrite these default settings with your graph settings like you are currently doing it in your fiddle.